# Binary Search tree time complexity

Tags: binary-search-tree

I am right now  working with a Binary Search tree. I wonder what is the Tim complexity for a Binary Search tree. More Specific what is the worst case Time complexity for the operation height, leaves and toString for a Binary Search tree and why?

Comment: None of the three operations you mention need the tree to be a *search* tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three operations have a  O(n) worst-case time complexity.

For `height`: all nodes will be visited when the tree is degenerate, and all nodes except one have exactly one child.

For `leaves`: each node will have to be visited in order to check whether they are a leave.

For `toString`: obviously all nodes need to be visited.

Comment: Thank you. How is it for size(), I said it is O(1), because size is a constant. Is that true?

Comment: No, in a pure tree it will also be O(n), as you need to *count* the nodes. But you can of course maintain extra information for the tree and keep track of its height, its size, its number of leaves,...etc, in separate variables, and then you can get a O(1) complexity. But then you have something more than just a tree.